# How to make a form generate an html template with input from the form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am making a website and I have a form on the homepage. When you submit the form with text I want to generate a html page from a template html code with a random name on my hosting. On the template I also want the input from the form to be included on the template. Anyone have tips on how to do this? I have been trying and looking up information on this topic for many hours and I can't figure it out. I have basic site programming skills. Below is what I have currently for PHP and HTML.

```
<?php
function giv3() {
    $myFile = "page/random.html";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
    fwrite($fh, $_POST['killa'])
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
TEXT: <input type="iptext" name="ipname"><br>
<input type="submit" name="killa">
</form>
```

Comment: It is customary to first show what you have tried so people know you are not just saying "I tried X". :-)